# How do I duplicate a component while preserving state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dnd

I have a component with `state` that gets updated as a result of some async operations. This component is part of some drag and drop UI, when a user begins a drag operation I need to render this component in a separate part of the application that's responsible for displaying the dragged element.

The problem is that if I render a component anew elsewhere, even if I pass the same props it will still have to run through the async operations before it can render the component from the same state as the drag source.

I thought I could make it work by doing something like this - render method of the component referencing the drag source:

```
render() {
    return (
        <DragSourceComponent ref={this.dragSourceComponentRef} />
    )
}
```

And a different component render method responsible for rendering the drag preview component:

```
renderDragPreview(dragSourceComponentRef) {
    return React.cloneElement(dragSourceComponentRef.current)
}
```

However this doesn't work because `dragSourceComponentRef.current` isn't considered a valid React element and even if it were, I don't think `React.cloneElement` copies a component's state (documentation isn't clear on this).

All of this in mind, what are some other options that I have?
Is it possible to say, pre-set a component's state before it's rendered for the first time? If that were the case I might be able to render the drag preview component with the same props and a cloned state and have it look exactly the same as the drag source element. Any other ideas/advice appreciated!

Comment: You just need the state to create a clone. You can use contextApi to share the state or redux.

Comment: I am interested to know if you solved this problem & if so how. I have the same use case of a DnD system.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to share a state with multiple similar components, not copy the siblings components state to the copied one.
You have two options here:

1. Move the DragSourceComponent' states to its parents components and get them via props;
2. Move the DragSourceComponent' states to a context, and get them via React.useContext() hook anywhere you want to